# Common table expression Alias Name issue

Tags: oracle, alias

I am trying to insert column values of BREAK_TIME and DIFF_OUT into my base table ezlabor_final_ak using Common Table Expression(CTE) but it is giving error message

> ORA-00904: "B"."IN_TIME": invalid identifier'

I am actually giving B as Alias name to my CTE but it is throwing error. Please help in rectifying the error. Please see the below code:

```
 INSERT INTO ezlabor_final_ak(BREAK_TIME,DIFF_IN_OUT)    
     SELECT BREAK_TIME,DIFF_IN_OUT FROM (
     WITH CTE_RN 
     AS
(
    SELECT t.out_time,t.in_time,t.Employee,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY In_Time) AS RN
    FROM ezlabor_final_ak t
    WHERE employee = 'JHW004605' AND TO_CHAR(in_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '21/11/2013' 
)
   SELECT
    a.Employee,TO_CHAR(a.in_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'),TO_CHAR(a.out_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'),a.RN as ARN,
   TO_CHAR(p.out_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'),TO_CHAR(p.in_time,'dd/mm/yyyy hh:mi:ss'),p.RN AS PRN,
    (a.in_time - p.out_time)*24*60 AS BREAK_TIME,
    (a.OUT_TIME - a.IN_TIME)*24*60 AS DIFF_IN_OUT
FROM CTE_RN a
LEFT JOIN CTE_RN  p
    ON p.EMPLOYEE = a.EMPLOYEE AND
       p.RN = a.RN - 1
       WHERE a.employee = 'JHW004605' AND TO_CHAR(a.in_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '21/11/2013' 
      ) b   
WHERE b.employee = 'JHW004605' AND TO_CHAR(b.in_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '21/11/2013'
```

Comment: The `b` is an alias to the derived table, not to the CTE. And that derived table has no column `in_time`.

Comment: @juergend Thank you for your reply. I am trying to copy the values of BREAK_TIME and DIFF_OUT fetched from the derived table into my base table ezlabor_final_ak  forthe condition WHERE b.employee = 'JHW004605' AND TO_CHAR(b.in_time, 'dd/mm/yyyy') = '21/11/2013' but these values are inserted into new rows instead of older rows for Employee ID JHW004605 whose in_time is '21/11/2013'. According to my understanding Insert statement is not locating the correct rows to insert the values. What do you think ?